# Variable not updated after lateinit declaration, unable to return

Tags: android, kotlin

OnCreateView Function

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        val view1 = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val recyclerview = view1!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)

        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)


        //val name3: Array<Articles> =


        recyclerview.adapter = CustomAdaptor(fetchJson())

        return view1

    }
```

Fetchjson function

```
    fun fetchJson(): Array<Articles> {
    println("Attempting to fetch JSON")
    val url1 = "https://go-api-api.herokuapp.com/"

    //var a1 = Articles(1, "rsdfd", "fdsadfd", 2345, 3)

    lateinit var name2: Array<Articles>  //Initialized name2

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url1).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            try {
                name2 = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Articles>::class.java)  //Updating value of name2
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                print("Error roroorirorr")
                print(e)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            println("Faild to execute request")
        }
    })
    return name2   //returning name2
}
```

The `CustomAdaptor` takes the input `Article` class. I have created a late initialized variable name2. In fetchjson, value of json does not get updated.

Error given by Android Studio:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property name2 has not been initialized

How should I declare the variable, so as to get it updated ?

Comment: `fetchJson(...)` such method has no sens as you are using async API ... [you should learn what is multithreading](https://ideone.com/PPHi95) in this example 3. is your return statment and 2 is `onResponse` call and `somestring` is your `name2`... as you see order is 1,3,2

Answer (score 0):

You are using AsyncTask (means you have called an URL and you are waiting for the response) , but fetchJson() method does not waiting to receive the answer from url and put it in name2 and return it. after you call fetchJson(), it starts your Asynctask and immediately reaches return name2. and because you havnt initialized name2 you get an error. so you should change your code to something like this :

```
  client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
        val body = response?.body()?.string()
        println(body)

        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

        try {
            name2 = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Articles>::class.java) 
            someMethodCallToReturnTheValue(name2)
         //Updating value of name2
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            print("Error roroorirorr")
            print(e)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
        println("Faild to execute request")
         someMethodCallToInformError()
    }
})
```

**UPDATE:** as  Marko Topolnik mentioned in comments , you can also use Coroutines in kotlin. 
checkout [this](https://medium.com/@macastiblancot/android-coroutines-getting-rid-of-runonuithread-and-callbacks-cleaner-thread-handling-and-more-234c0a9bd8eb) link to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

you declare variable as a class level static variable e.g:-

```
           public static int a = 10;
```

you can easily update your variable ,and also you can update this variable from another class but in package..

Comment: he is using kotlin not java ...  also it is terrible idea to use static anyway

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
// DONT DO: lateinit var name2: Array<Articles>  //Initialized name2
// DO: var name2 = arrayListOf<Articles>()  //Initialized name2
```

Comment: It's invalid syntax. You can't declare the type as an initializer method...

Comment: Sorry, is this: var name2 = arrayListOf<Articles>()